# object of type 'Activation' has no len()

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, networkx

I'm trying to build my GraphSAGE model using Keras but I get the following error:

```
/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/python /Users/name/PycharmProjects/keras_autoencoder/NodeEmbeddings.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
2020-03-26 22:35:08.640725: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2020-03-26 22:35:08.655308: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f9aa4872710 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-03-26 22:35:08.655323: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
link_classification: using 'ip' method to combine node embeddings into edge embeddings
/Users/name/PycharmProjects/keras_autoencoder/NodeEmbeddings.py:65: UserWarning: Update your `Model` call to the Keras 2 API: `Model(inputs=[<tf.Tenso..., outputs=Tensor("re...)`
  model = Model(input=x_inp, output=prediction)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/PycharmProjects/keras_autoencoder/NodeEmbeddings.py", line 65, in <module>
    model = Model(input=x_inp, output=prediction)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 241, in _init_graph_network
    self.inputs, self.outputs)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1434, in _map_graph_network
    tensor_index=tensor_index)
  File "/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1415, in build_map
    for i in range(len(node.inbound_layers)):
TypeError: object of type 'Activation' has no len()
```

Here is is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import stellargraph as sg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


from keras import layers, optimizers, losses, metrics, Model

from keras import optimizers

from stellargraph.mapper import GraphSAGENodeGenerator, GraphSAGELinkGenerator
from stellargraph.layer import GraphSAGE, link_classification
from stellargraph.data import UnsupervisedSampler


from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


# Loading Data --------------

# Define Edges and Nodes (from_pandas_edgelist creates Nodes automatically from the parsed edgelist)
edgelist= pd.read_csv("./data/cora/cora.cites", sep='\t', header=None, names=['target', 'source'])
edgelist['label'] = 'cites'
Gnx = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edgelist, edge_attr='label')
nx.set_node_attributes(Gnx, 'paper', 'label')

# Define Node features
feature_names = ["w_{}".format(ii) for ii in range(1433)]
column_names = feature_names + ['subject']
node_data = pd.read_csv("./data/cora/cora.content", sep='\t', header=None, names=column_names)
node_with_features = node_data[feature_names]

# Create StellarGraph object
G = sg.StellarGraph(Gnx, node_features=node_with_features)


# Specify model and training parameter
nodes = list(G.nodes())
number_of_walks = 1
length = 5
batch_size = 50
epochs = 4
num_samples = [10, 5]

unsupervised_samples = UnsupervisedSampler(G, nodes=nodes, length=length, number_of_walks=number_of_walks)
train_gen = GraphSAGELinkGenerator(G,batch_size, num_samples)#.flow(unsupervised_samples)


# Creating GraphSAGE model
layer_sizes =[50,50]
graphsage = GraphSAGE(layer_sizes=layer_sizes, generator=train_gen, bias=True, dropout=0.0, normalize='l2')

x_inp, x_out = graphsage.build()
prediction = link_classification(output_dim=1, output_act='hard_sigmoid', edge_embedding_method='ip')(x_out)

model = Model(input=x_inp, output=prediction)

model.compile(
    optimizers=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
    loss=losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy],
)


history = model.fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    workers=4,
    shuffle=True,
)

# Node Embedding
x_inp_src = x_inp[0::2]
x_out_src = x_out[0]
embedding_model = Model(inputs=x_inp_src, outputs=x_out_src)
node_ids = node_data.index
node_gen = GraphSAGENodeGenerator(G, batch_size,num_samples).flow(node_ids)
node_embeddings = embedding_model.predict_generator(node_gen, workers=4, verbose=1)
```

As I'm not sure what this error tells me because the Activation methods in Keras API don't have len() implemented. I've read couple of other topics on this error but it doesn't work out either. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exact problem/solution would depend on what version of `stellargraph` you're using, but if it's not a problem for you to use the latest version (`0.11.0` at time of writing), I've made some adjustments to make it work:

```
import networkx as nx
import stellargraph as sg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# UPDATED: import from tensorflow.keras instead of keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers, losses, metrics, Model

from stellargraph.mapper import GraphSAGENodeGenerator, GraphSAGELinkGenerator
from stellargraph.layer import GraphSAGE, link_classification
from stellargraph.data import UnsupervisedSampler


from sklearn import preprocessing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE


# Loading Data --------------

# Define Edges and Nodes (from_pandas_edgelist creates Nodes automatically from the parsed edgelist)
edgelist= pd.read_csv("./data/cora/cora.cites", sep='\t', header=None, names=['target', 'source'])
edgelist['label'] = 'cites'
Gnx = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(edgelist, edge_attr='label')
nx.set_node_attributes(Gnx, 'paper', 'label')

# Define Node features
feature_names = ["w_{}".format(ii) for ii in range(1433)]
column_names = feature_names + ['subject']
node_data = pd.read_csv("./data/cora/cora.content", sep='\t', header=None, names=column_names)
node_with_features = node_data[feature_names]

# Create StellarGraph object
G = sg.StellarGraph(Gnx, node_features=node_with_features)


# Specify model and training parameter
nodes = list(G.nodes())
number_of_walks = 1
length = 5
batch_size = 50
epochs = 4
num_samples = [10, 5]

unsupervised_samples = UnsupervisedSampler(G, nodes=nodes, length=length, number_of_walks=number_of_walks)
train_gen = GraphSAGELinkGenerator(G,batch_size, num_samples)


# Creating GraphSAGE model
layer_sizes =[50,50]
graphsage = GraphSAGE(layer_sizes=layer_sizes, generator=train_gen, bias=True, dropout=0.0, normalize='l2')

x_inp, x_out = graphsage.build()
prediction = link_classification(output_dim=1, output_act='hard_sigmoid', edge_embedding_method='ip')(x_out)

# UPDATED: `inputs` and `outputs` instead of `input` and `output`
model = Model(inputs=x_inp, outputs=prediction)

model.compile(
    # UPDATED: parameter name `optimizer` instead of `optimizers`
    optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3),
    loss=losses.binary_crossentropy,
    metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy],
)


history = model.fit_generator(
    # UPDATED: we need to call .flow before passing it to `fit_generator`
    train_gen.flow(unsupervised_samples), 
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    workers=4,
    shuffle=True,
)

# Node Embedding
x_inp_src = x_inp[0::2]
x_out_src = x_out[0]
embedding_model = Model(inputs=x_inp_src, outputs=x_out_src)
node_ids = node_data.index
node_gen = GraphSAGENodeGenerator(G, batch_size,num_samples).flow(node_ids)
node_embeddings = embedding_model.predict_generator(node_gen, workers=4, verbose=1)

print(node_embeddings)
```

I wrote a comment for each line I updated (the `UPDATED` ones) - other than some minor typos, I suspect the main issue came from importing `keras` instead of `tensorflow.keras`. With the release of tensorflow >= 2.0, `stellargraph` uses the keras API that's part of tensorflow's core API, and it's [recommended that users that use keras with the tensorflow backend switch to using `tensorflow.keras`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras#multi-backend-keras-and-tfkeras)

> At this time, we recommend that Keras users who use multi-backend Keras with the TensorFlow backend switch to tf.keras in TensorFlow 2.0. tf.keras is better maintained and has better integration with TensorFlow features (eager execution, distribution support and other).

Hope that helps!

---

As a side note, some of the other methods being used are deprecated in `0.11.0` - they should work as is for now, but will produce deprecation warnings and will be removed in the future:

Constructing a stellargraph from networkx:

```
G = sg.StellarGraph(Gnx, node_features=node_with_features)

# switch to
G = sg.StellarGraph.from_networkx(Gnx, node_features=node_with_features)
```

Getting input and output tensors from a stellargraph model:

```
x_inp, x_out = graphsage.build()

# switch to
x_inp, x_out = graphsage.in_out_tensors()
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue! I've also switched to in_out_tensors()